# ClickOnce deployed application has blinking cursor but no focus

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

We have an application deployed via ClickOnce which has a weird problem.  When you start the application and we show our login dialog the User name field will have a blinking cursor as if the control has focus but as soon as you start typing nothing happens.  You have to actually click the dialog window to give it focus.

If you click away again though the User name field won't have a blinking cursor anymore so it's almost like the control has focus but not really?

Has anyone ran into this problem?  We need our app to have focus when it starts...

One thing to mention is we're actually using a UI framework (XF.UI.Smart) which has a ShellPresenter/ShellView idea.  The shell is being hidden while the login dialog shows.  Could this hiding of the main window be the problem?

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried calling `.Focus()` on the window / control ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it doesn't work.  I added another bit of detail about how the dialog is shown..